# My tortoise is not moving

Tags: tortoises

I have a star tortoise of 2 years old. just this morning I have kept it in water and left it, I don't know when it moved away from the box and fell down from four floors.i just found it and its ok from outside but its not moving.I don't know what happened to it. please help me to make it normal.

Comment: You should see a vet as soon as possible. There might be no external injuries, but it's possible your tortoise suffered broken bones where they aren't visible, as well as internal injuries and potentially shock.

Comment: In an emergency, ___ask a vet, not the internet.___ The time you spend waiting for us to answer may be the difference between life and death.

Comment: I agree that it's a duplicate because my answer would be the same. Even if there are no visible signs of injury, that doesn't mean there aren't internal injuries.